# Lognormal Stock Price Distribution in R

Tags: r

My goal is to obtain a lognormal distribution of stock prices, that I can then use to calculate the expected utilty an agent would receive from holding such stocks. But I am a bit stuck on how to achieve this. The distribution of stock prices is lognormal with volatility *σ* and expected returns *r* obtained from the capital asset pricing model.

For example, *σ* = 0.01825838 and *r* = 0.13053162. I tried to generate the distribution of stock prices with:

```
dist <- rlnorm(1000, 0.13053162, 0.01825838)
```

However, this distribution is normally distributed, and not lognormally distributed. How can I generate this distribution that I subsequently can use to calculate the expected utility assuming the agent have constant relative risk aversion:

[image: utility]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525179/normal-approximation-to-the-log-normal-distribution) on Mathematics StacksExchange that the lognormal approximates the normal for small sigma. So you are sampling from lognormal with the code you provide, but since you have a small sigma, it can be approximated by the normal.

You can see the approximation of the normal visually by varying sigma
    
`hist(rlnorm(1000, meanlog = 0.1305, sdlog = 0.500)
hist(rlnorm(1000, meanlog = 0.1305, sdlog = 0.018)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the second part of your question, but to create a lognormal distribution, you can use the property that if X follows a log-normal distribution and Y = ln(X), then Y follows a normal distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

So something like:

```
set.seed(1234)
dist <- rnorm(1000, 1, .5)
ldist <- exp(dist)
hist(ldist)
```

This looks log-normal to me.